# Adding button to host element using a angular directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm developing a directive, whose functionality is to add two buttons to the host/parent element. 
Host/parent element will be a textarea element.
I tried to achieve using renderer2 createElement, appendChild methods. Renderer two is creating these buttons and adding to host element like this.

```
<textarea _ngcontent-c0="" appmarkdown=""><div _ngcontent-c0=""><button _ngcontent-c0="">Hello world</button></div></textarea>
```

But this way button is not visible. Could anyone help me with this.

code for my directive.

```
enter code here          import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter, Renderer2, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

      @Directive({
        selector: '[appMarkDown]',
        host:{
          '(keyup)': 'onKey($event.target.value)'
        }
      })
      export class MarkDownDirective implements OnInit {

        constructor(private renderer:Renderer2,private element:ElementRef) { }

        @Output() valuechange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

        private nativeElement : Node;

        ngOnInit() {
          this.nativeElement = this.element.nativeElement;
          const div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
          const button= this.renderer.createElement('button');
          const text = this.renderer.createText('Hello world');
          this.renderer.appendChild(button, text);
          this.renderer.appendChild(div, button);
          this.renderer.appendChild(this.nativeElement, div);
          this.renderer.nextSibling(this.nativeElement)
        }

        onKey(event:KeyboardEvent){
          this.valuechange.emit(event);
        }
      }
```

Comment: add a working example using stackblitz or plunker, where your error could be produced?

Comment: @NitishkumarSingh there is no error. Issue in my case is button element is appended in between textarea element. I want that button to be attached next to the parent element. no inside of it.

Comment: Seriously, why? Why use a directive and not just a component. When you want something HTML rendered, just use a component and put the HTML in the template. That's what components are for, not directives.

Comment: This seems you are passing value to directive `appmarkdown=""` instead of this `appmarkdown`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since, you are trying to add an button next to an `<textarea></textarea>`using attribute directive. The correct approach would be to create an component rather than creating directive. Component approach is being used by all the frameworks.

> An Attribute directive changes the appearance or behavior of a DOM
>   element.

But here, you are actually changing the structure itself. If it's something you want to do with the help of attribute directive only, then you should apply directive on `<div>`, where you can insert `<textarea>` and `<button>` within it.

If you don't want to change your code, then you should go with

```
 ngOnInit() {
          this.nativeElement = this.element.nativeElement;
          const div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
          const button= this.renderer.createElement('button');
          const text = this.renderer.createText('Hello world');
          this.renderer.appendChild(button, text);
          this.renderer.appendChild(div, button);
          this.renderer.insertBefore(this.element.nativeElement.parentNode, div, this.element.nativeElement.nextSibling);
        }
```

Here is [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zs7p7m) for working solution

Comment: Happy to help, please accept the answer to close question